# How to Stopping System-Versioning on a System-Versioned Temporal Table in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, temporal-tables

I have a table that has system versioning (temporal table), but I can not see a design environment visually. I do it because I can see the `SYSTEM_VERSIONING` clause has been used. I would like to have temporarily Stop and then enable it.
Who can advise me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot delete rows from a temporal history table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746197/cannot-delete-rows-from-a-temporal-history-table)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

My problem was solved when i using following query:

```
-- SET SYSTEM_VERSIONING TO OFF
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF)
GO

** Do what ever you want to **

-- SET SYSTEM_VERSIONING TO ON
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
SET 
    (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[MyTable_Archive] , DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON ))
GO
```

Comment: Hi @Aiyob , Do we need to use the statement - DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON here and is it require,

Comment: The option DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON is not required. It is the default and performs various checks before turning the historization back on. Here is the corresponding SQL Docs documentation by Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-table-system-consistency-checks?view=sql-server-ver16.

Comment: You should be careful with this answer as it will most likely destroy your continous history. When you set the system_versioning off you should also drop your period for system_time. You should also be aware of that DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON "only" checks if ValidTo >= ValidFrom and NOT checks for gaps in the history...

Comment: You can use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Peter-Schneider/4c2d7f5c5f968dfb89592561f464f30c) to play around and check yourself.

Answer (score 9):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF);   

** Do what ever you want to **

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = [dbo].[MyTable_Archive]));
```

See this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/stopping-system-versioning-on-a-system-versioned-temporal-table) for more info

**UPDATED 22/05/2023** : Added HISTORY_TABLE argument to keep the answer relevant. When the answer was originally written, this was a new feature and generally not required.

Comment: This creates temporary table and does not use previous history table!!!

Comment: Adding to @Dixtosa comment, this answer does not specity the "HISTORY_TABLE" argument, and thus another table is created. From Microsoft docs "When turning system versioning back on, don't forget to specify the HISTORY_TABLE argument. Failing to do so results in a new history table being created and associated with the current table. The original history table can still exist as a normal table but won't be associated with the current table." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/stopping-system-versioning-on-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 2):

It seems that after doing `SET( SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF )`, the `PERIOD FOR` option on the table is also reset.

So this works for me:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
    SET (
        SYSTEM_VERSIONING = OFF
    )

GO

/* Do stuff here. */

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
    ADD PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME ( ValidFrom, ValidTo );

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable
    SET (
        SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (
            HISTORY_TABLE          = dbo.MyTable_History,
            DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK = ON
        ));
```

I assume it's possible to combine the last two commands into a single `ALTER TABLE` statement but I haven't found the magic incantation yet.

Comment: You can only add the period for system_time if you have dropped it beforehand. So you should add an ```ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] DROP PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME``` before /* Do your stuff here. */