# EF6 Temporal table - how to remove data without adding historical record

Tags: sql, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working with EF Core 6.0 and SQL Server. I have an **Articles** table (with associated temporal table named **ArticlesHistory**).

My user can delete/modify their articles, and then undo the changes thanks to the temporal table.

However, now I want to create a feature that allows user to **delete an article **permanently**.**
So I wonder if there is any way that we can remove record in **Articles** table, **without inserting** historical record into **ArticlesHistory** table?

Comment: Why do you want this? The whole point of using temporal tables is that versions are preserved. If SQL Server did *exactly* what you asked you'd end up with an older record of the row, not a total delete. You'd have to delete all history records to get what you want. Which isn't possible. If you have a retention policy older records will be deleted automatically after a time anyway.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand the fallibility here, thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: What are you trying to do though? You can delete records from the History table if you first disable versioning and then re-enable it, but that's obviously something that should be done carefully by a DBA. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746197/cannot-delete-rows-from-a-temporal-history-table) asks how to do that, but as the comments say, this schema change can be blocked by indexes, views, check constraints etc. If you want to permanently delete data for eg GDPR or privacy reasons that's acceptable. It's not if want to add a `Delete Permantently` button to the app

Comment: If you want to delete large amounts of historical data you could [use partitioning on the history table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/partitioning-with-temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16) and switch out old History partitions